# How to check if mouse is over a button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, click, mouseover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Time Delay on Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638179/time-delay-on-trigger)

I am using a few buttons in WPF for displaying images from various folders. The `Click` mode for all the buttons is `Hover`. For some button, after hovering, it is routed to a function `OnButtonClick`. What I want to do is, ONLY after the mouse is over the button for `X` seconds, the processing inside the function `OnButtonClick` should be done.

EDIT:
XAML Code:

```
    <Button Name="Dresses" Content="Dresses" Click="OnButtonClickDresses" Grid.Row="2" Height="34" Width="85" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="5"  FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" ClickMode="Hover">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

C# Code:

```
    private void OnButtonClickDresses(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            //Code for delay

            //Code which should run only if mouse on button after 5 seconds

    }
```

Comment: here is the same case at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638179/time-delay-on-trigger)

Answer (score 3):

Use a trigger on the MouseOver event. Once the mouse is over your control, start a timer. If it elapses while the mouse is still over the control, simulate a click.

See a small example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/a39c0dc8-7446-4a05-82c7-cdbda2171e2f)

Comment: I have added my XML and C# code. Could you give a minimum code example for what I want to achieve? I couldn't pick up anything from the link you gave.