# How to check if mouse is over a button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, click, delay, mouseover

Before I start, I have to say this. I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638179/time-delay-on-trigger). And I dont see how its a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908968/how-to-check-if-mouse-is-over-a-button-in-wpf) that I posted a few hours ago.

My original post as it is:

I am using a few buttons in WPF for displaying images from various folders. The `Click` mode for all the buttons is `Hover`. For some button, after hovering, it is routed to a function `OnButtonClick`. What I want to do is, ONLY after the mouse is over the button for `X` seconds, the processing inside the function `OnButtonClick` should be done.

XAML Code:

```
    <Button Name="Dresses" MouseEnter="onMouseEnter" MouseLeave="onMouseLeave" Content="Dresses" Grid.Row="2" Height="25" Width="85" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="5"  FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" ClickMode="Hover">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

C# Code:

```
    private void OnButtonClickDresses(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            //Code for delay

            //Code which should run only if mouse on button after 5 seconds

    }
```

PS: I am a beginner in WPF and C#. So if you can post a minimum working example I'd be actually very grateful.

Comment: You can check my updated answer.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? I don't see any attempt, just worthless comments, this isn't hard. As `jams` pointed out the event you want to use is `MouseEnter`  This still is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638179/time-delay-on-trigger

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is, I dont know what to try. I am trying the suggestions made by some people in the answers but they dont seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample application for you.

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace MyWPF App
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    DateTime dt;
    DispatcherTimer t;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        t = new DispatcherTimer();
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);

    }
    private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dt=DateTime.Now;
        t.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        t.IsEnabled = true;


    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((DateTime.Now - dt).Seconds >= 5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");// Here you can put your code which you want to execute after 5 seconds.
        }

    }

    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        t.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I could do this based on the code that I've quoted?

Comment: Why you want to wait for 5 second?

Comment: It doesnt need to be 5 seconds. It can be say `X` seconds. What I want to do, if the mouse is over a button for more than `X` seconds, only then should a particular process assigned to that button should occur.

Comment: @Karan Thakkar : Please tell me Is it working for you or not?

Comment: It doesnt do what you say it should do. When I hover over the button for any number of seconds, there is no output.

Comment: How you are using this code copy pest will not work. You need to change namspace first. It is tried and tested code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18104/discussion-between-karan-thakkar-and-jams)

Answer (score 2):

You can use MouseEnter to start a Timer which has an interval of X seconds. On MouseLeave you stop this Timer. Now you put the code from the OnButtonClickDresses-method in the Timer_Tick method.

Sample:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer dt;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);//wait for 5 Seconds
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
    }

    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do code
    }

    private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Start();
    }

    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Stop();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
    <Button Name="Dresses" MouseEnter="button1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="button1_MouseLeave" Content="Dresses" Grid.Row="2" Height="25" Width="85" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="5"  FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand"
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

Comment: It doesnt do what you say it should do. When I hover over the button for any number of seconds, there is no output.

Comment: Did you add your code in the dt_Tick - method? Either you have to change the method name of the MouseEnter and MouseLeave Event in your XAML or in my code. See my edit.

Comment: Yes. I added a simple `MessageBox` just to check if it was entering that loop. But no, it wasnt.

Comment: It works after that. But @jams told me that in the chat before I read your comment. So I am marking his answer as correct. But your answer works correctly too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use it in the method:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (5000);
```

For the reason that will freeze your interface.

For that you should use some sort of asynchronous task.
I recommend:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew (() =>
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (5000);
})
. ContinueWith (() =>
{
     / / Code after 5 seconds
}
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext ());
```

Although I do not think it is ideal because it can remove the mouse over, and put back. This can cause confusion.

My recommended approach:

Use the events MouseEnter and MouseLeave, and classes

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch 
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
```

I do not understand exactly the logic you need, but I think with these two classes and the events you can do what you want.

Comment: The logic is that, I will be controlling the mouse using my hand movements, using Kinect. So to avoid accidentally hovering on some button, I am adding the delay. So if the mouse is on some button for a few seconds, then the button will be activated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work OK for an arbitrary number of buttons...

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="myButton1" Content="Button 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="HoverButton_Click" MouseEnter="HoverButton_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="HoverButton_MouseLeave"/>
        <Button Name="myButton2" Content="Button 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="HoverButton_Click" MouseEnter="HoverButton_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="HoverButton_MouseLeave"/>
        <TextBox Name="myTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="147" Margin="34,91,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="232"/>
    </Grid>
```

Code:

```
    private Dictionary<Button, System.Threading.Timer> buttonTimers = new Dictionary<Button, System.Threading.Timer>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void HoverTime(object state)
    {
        var thisButton = state as Button;

        thisButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            thisButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
        });
    }

    private void HoverButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;

        myTextBox.Text += "Delayed hover: " + button.Content + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    private void HoverButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var thisButton = sender as Button;

        var t = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(HoverTime), sender, 2500, Timeout.Infinite);

        buttonTimers.Add(thisButton, t);
    }

    private void HoverButton_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var thisButton = sender as Button;

        if (buttonTimers.ContainsKey(thisButton))
        {
            buttonTimers[thisButton].Dispose();
            buttonTimers.Remove(thisButton);
        }
    }
```